# adding image to the widget of magento

Tags: magento

i am developing a widget. For that i have to add images to the widget in magento.. any help??

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. You need to add images to the site design? Or is there something else you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!. This can be done by calling the getSkinUrl() command that will give the url of the skin where images are kept. Then the images can be accessed easily.